# Mostrar Quantidade de itens por categoria em loja virtual?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou com uma dúvida:

Tenho varias categorias em meu site  e gostaria que mostrasse a quantidade de itens tem em cada categoria. Exemplo:

Está assim:

- Acessórios
- Brinquedos
- Games
- Informática

Quero que fique assim:

- Acessórios (3)
- Brinquedos (1)
- Games (2)
- Informática (0)

Como fazer isso sem estourar o limite de Consulta via PDO?

Comment: O que é este limite de consulta?

Comment: Adicione uma parte do seu código para que alguém possa criar uma solução. Faça um Tour pelo site - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour - e entenda como fazer perguntas.

Answer (score 1):

Use o count() e group by.

Sua query deve ficar parecido com isto:

```
select cat.nome, count(prod.id) as contagem
from categoria as cat
  inner join produto as p on p.id_categoria = cat.id
group by cat.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso tenho que fazer uma function? As informações dos itens se encontram apenas em uma tabela ("PRODUTOS"), só estão em colunas diferentes.

Seria mais ou menos assim?

/***************************************************/
function qtdCat($cat)
{
  $quantidade = select cat.nome, count(prod.id) WHERE categoria = '$cat' as contagem
  from categoria as cat
  inner join produto as p on p.id_categoria = cat.id
  group by cat.id

return $quantidade;
}

```
Acessórios   <?=qtdCat("aces");?>
Brinquedos   <?=qtdCat("brinq");?>
Games        <?=qtdCat("games");?>
Informática  <?=qtdCat("info");?>
```

/***************************************************/

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o Problema conforme descrito abaixo:

```
<!--=============================================================-->
<!--===Inicio - Essa Parte trata a quantidade por Categoria======-->

    <?php
    $categoria = array(); //Declarado um Array sem Tamanho
    $contitensCat = 0;    //Essa Variavel vai contar quantas categorias tem Geral
    $itensCat = 0;        //Essa vai entrar na function e contar a quantidade de cada categoria de quem esta chamando a function

            $buscaSegura = $pdo->prepare("SELECT categoria FROM produtos"); //Faz a Busca da coluna inteira da Categoria do banco de dados
            $buscaSegura->execute(); // Executa o Select
            $consultaBanco = $buscaSegura->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($consultaBanco as $consulta) 
    {
        array_push($categoria, $consulta['categoria']);
        $contitensCat++; //A cada linha Encontrada essa variavel vai ser incrementada
    }


function cont($palavra,$categoria,$contitensCat,$itensCat)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < $contitensCat; $i++)
    {
        if($categoria[$i]==$palavra)//Se achar a palavra, ai entra nesse IF
        {
            $itensCat++;
        }
    }
    return $itensCat;//Retorna  Quantidade de itens achado de acordo com o parâmetro passado a função
}
    ?>

<!--======Fim - Essa Parte trata a quantidade por Categoria======-->
<!--=============================================================-->

 - Acessórios (<?=cont("ac",$categoria,$contitensCat,$itensCat);?>)
 - Brinquedos  (<?=cont("brinq",$categoria,$contitensCat,$itensCat);?>)
 - Games (<?=cont("games",$categoria,$contitensCat,$itensCat);?>)
 - Informática (<?=cont("inf",$categoria,$contitensCat,$itensCat);?>)
```